# mssql + sssd Ubuntu cannot login via AD group

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, active-directory, kerberos

I've got mssql  14.0.3192.2-2 setup unter Ubuntu; I have joined my machine to AD as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-2017).

The Windows login via SSMS and sqlcmd works if I add invididual AD users, but not if I add groups.

Also, when I try to get the "Effective Permissions" for the group under Server Properties / Permissions, I get an error `"Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'UserName', error code 0x80090304."`

I can do kinit without problems, I can query users via `id` (returns all assigned groups), I can query group members via `members` which successfully returns all group members.

If you have any idea what could be wrong I'd really appreciate your help!

Basic config:

```
Domain: ad.xxxx.com
Hostname: linux.ad.xxxx.com
NetBIOS name: LINUX
DC1, DC2: heart.ad.xxxx.com, file.ad.xxxx.com
AD DNS resolves linux.ad.xxxx.com to 10.0.10.13
Reverse DNS resolves 10.0.10.13 to linux.ad.xxxx.com
```

The SQL server host is located in a DMZ, with ports 88, 3268, 389, 1433 open.

My mssql.keytab:

```
slot KVNO Principal
---- ---- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    2 MSSQLSvc/linux.ad.xxxx.com:1433@AD.XXXX.COM
   2    2 MSSQLSvc/linux.ad.xxxx.com:1433@AD.XXXX.COM
   3    2           MSSQLSvc/LINUX:1433@AD.XXXX.COM
   4    2           MSSQLSvc/LINUX:1433@AD.XXXX.COM
   5    3                        LINUX$@AD.XXXX.COM
   6    3                        LINUX$@AD.XXXX.COM
   7    3                        LINUX$@AD.XXXX.COM
   8    3                        LINUX$@AD.XXXX.COM
   9    3                        LINUX$@AD.XXXX.COM
```

My /etc/krb5.keytab:

```
slot KVNO Principal
---- ---- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    3                        LINUX$@AD.XXXX.COM
   2    3                        LINUX$@AD.XXXX.COM
   3    3                        LINUX$@AD.XXXX.COM
   4    3                        LINUX$@AD.XXXX.COM
   5    3                        LINUX$@AD.XXXX.COM
   6    3                    host/LINUX@AD.XXXX.COM
   7    3                    host/LINUX@AD.XXXX.COM
   8    3                    host/LINUX@AD.XXXX.COM
   9    3                    host/LINUX@AD.XXXX.COM
  10    3                    host/LINUX@AD.XXXX.COM
  11    3         host/linux.ad.xxxx.com@AD.XXXX.COM
  12    3         host/linux.ad.xxxx.com@AD.XXXX.COM
  13    3         host/linux.ad.xxxx.com@AD.XXXX.COM
  14    3         host/linux.ad.xxxx.com@AD.XXXX.COM
  15    3         host/linux.ad.xxxx.com@AD.XXXX.COM
  16    3       RestrictedKrbHost/LINUX@AD.XXXX.COM
  17    3       RestrictedKrbHost/LINUX@AD.XXXX.COM
  18    3       RestrictedKrbHost/LINUX@AD.XXXX.COM
  19    3       RestrictedKrbHost/LINUX@AD.XXXX.COM
  20    3       RestrictedKrbHost/LINUX@AD.XXXX.COM
  21    3 RestrictedKrbHost/linux.ad.xxxx.com@AD.XXXX.COM
  22    3 RestrictedKrbHost/linux.ad.xxxx.com@AD.XXXX.COM
  23    3 RestrictedKrbHost/linux.ad.xxxx.com@AD.XXXX.COM
  24    3 RestrictedKrbHost/linux.ad.xxxx.com@AD.XXXX.COM
  25    3 RestrictedKrbHost/linux.ad.xxxx.com@AD.XXXX.COM
```

In AD I have a user `linux.sql` which has the following SPNs assigned:

```
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=linux.sql,CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=xxxx,DC=com:
        MSSQLSvc/LINUX:1433
        MSSQLSvc/linux.ad.xxxx.com:1433
```

Also, the SQL server has a machine account `LINUX`.

Comment: My mssql.conf:

`[sqlagent]
enabled = false

[EULA]
accepteula = Y

[network]
kerberoskeytabfile = /var/opt/mssql/secrets/mssql.keytab
tlscert = /var/opt/mssql/secrets/ssl/cert.pem
tlskey = /var/opt/mssql/secrets/ssl/privkey.pem
tlsprotocols = 1.2
forceencryption = 1`

Comment: My sssd,conf:

`[sssd]
domains = ad.xyz.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
default_domain_suffix = ad.xyz.com

[domain/ad.xyz.com]
ad_domain = ad.xyz.com
krb5_realm = AD.XYZ.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli 
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d`

Comment: My krb5.conf:

`[libdefaults]
 default_realm = AD.XYZ.COM
 kdc_timesync = 1
 ccache_type = 4
 forwardable = true
 proxiable = true
 fcc-mit-ticketflags = true

[realms]

[domain_realm]`